# php echo htmlspecialchars problems with <h2>, hyperlinks, images etc. Need solution

Tags: php, mysql

Fetch data from mysql.
Then echo with `echo htmlspecialchars( $content['MainText'] , ENT_NOQUOTES, "UTF-8");`.

Tried to echo without `htmlspecialchars` javascript like `<script> alert('Hello');</script>` and saw pop up box. So it is not good to echo without `htmlspecialchars`.

But with `htmlspecialchars` can not correctly display hyperlinks and images and also `<h2>`, `<span>` etc. Also not acceptable.

At the moment tried to replace some characters like

```
$content_main_text_modified = 
str_replace( 
array( '&lt;br/&gt;', '&lt;br&gt;', '&lt;/a&gt;', "&gt;", '&lt;a', '&lt;div', '&lt;img', '&lt;/div', '&lt;h2', '&lt;/h2', 'amp;amp;', '&lt;span', '&lt;/span' ), 
array( '<br/>', '<br>', '</a>', ">", '<a', '<div', '<img', '</div', '<h2', '</h2', '', '<span', '</span' ), 
( htmlspecialchars( $content['MainText'] , ENT_NOQUOTES, "UTF-8") ) 
);
echo $content_main_text_modified;
```

My idea is not to replace sole `&lt;` with `<`, but instead to replace `&lt;` together `br`, `a`, `<h2`. So if in mysql would be like `<script>` it would not execute.

Want to check (get opions) if my idea is safe idea? And possibly some recommendations.

Comment: Can I ask why you are adding html into the database

Answer (score 1):

I think a different idea would be to stop it being stored that way in the first place so that you can just echo it. What you are referring to is an xss attack where someone can enter JavaScript that can then be executed on another users browser take a look at this link for more detailed information about xss [click here](http://www.sitepoint.com/php-security-cross-site-scripting-attacks-xss/).

As for a way to remove it what I would do is some form of validation on the imputed data there are so many ways to do this I would suggest reading the link above and that will give you an idea how to stop it and mean you can then just do a simple echo. Doing validation like this will also help to prevent sql injection attacks although that will require some more work.

This wont work every time and some people also suggest that you use htmlspecialchars but when you are working with html this causes issues as you know, you just have to make your best attempt no system can stop everything.

Not knowing exactly what your are doing it is impossible to say but you might find it useful to use some kind of template engine so the HTML is sepperate from the code and you can use the function `htmlspecialchars()` as you can then just pass out text to the template.

Comment: I have one (only) page that shows content. It fetches mysql based on `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`. Sometimes in text (in input form, which sends data to mysql) must add hyperlink or set <h2>. All input goes to mysql... At the moment no idea how otherwise i can store input... Created something like CMS for myself

Comment: You can still store the data in mysql all you need to do is add some initial validation if you are using hyperlinks you can easily use JavaScript and PHP to check that it is a valid link before saving it to the DB. As for the HTML that is a bit more tricky let me think about that one.

Answer (score 0):

Use `strip_tags($content['MainText'], '<a><h2><div><span><br><img>');`

Or you can use htmlspecialchars then use this `preg_replace('#&lt;(/?(?:a|h2|div|span|br|img))&gt;#', '<\1>', $html);`, for example:

```
$content_main_text_modified = htmlspecialchars($content['MainText']);
$content_main_text_modified = reg_replace('#&lt;(/?(?:a|h2|div|span|br|img))&gt;#', '<$1>', $content_main_text_modified);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://htmlpurifier.org/ and the HTML.Allowed directive; where you can set tags that are allowed.